# Duda en bucle while afuera de una función

Tags: javascript

Estoy iniciando a aprender el lenguaje de JavaScript y tengo un duda. Estoy intentando hacer un juego de comparación de números mayores y menores,
para eso se ejecuta un prompt en donde se pide escribir los números y de ahí hacer la comparación de cual es mayor y cual es el menor.
Se trata de que en lugar de números escriban letras o texto y arrojar un alert de que no son números e intentarlo otra vez. Esto se ejecuta un bucle while, pero no lo hace de la manera que yo esperaba ¿A que se debe esto?

```
var number1;
var number2;
var noNumber = false;
randomNumber();

function randomNumber () {
    number1 = prompt("Escribe un numero");
    number2 = prompt("Escribe otro numero");

    if (isNaN(number1)== true || isNaN(number2)== true) {
        alert("No son numeros");
        noNumber = true;
    } else if ( number1 > number2 ) {
        document.write( number1 + " Es el numero mayor");
        noNumber = false;
    } else if (number1 < number2) {
        document.write( number2 + " Es el numero mayor");
        noNumber = false;
    } else {
        document.write("Ningun numero es mayor");
    }
}

while ( noNumber == true ) {
    alert("Intentalo otra vez");
    randomNumber();        
}

document.write(randomNumber());
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se ejecuta y cual es el comportamiento esperado?

Comment: cuando se compare el numero mayor se cumpla y arroje el resultado de cual es el numero mayor, pero si la persona escribe texto en lugar de números se ejecutara el bucle hasta que el usuario escriba números.

Comment: @PoloMoreno Estas comparando strings como si fueran números. Intenta con 12 y 2 para que veas que no te va a resultar lo que esperas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás llamando dos veces a `randomNumber()` basta con llamarlo una sola vez:

Además no es necesario compara valores `boolean` con `== true` basta solo con la expresión que devuelve bool:

Ejemplo:

```
if (isNaN(number1) || isNaN(number2))
```

Otro error, me parece que en el último `else` le falta un `noNumber = false;`

```js
    var number1;
    var number2;
    var noNumber = false;
    randomNumber();

    function randomNumber () {
        number1 = prompt("Escribe un numero");
        number2 = prompt("Escribe otro numero");
  
        if (isNaN(number1) || isNaN(number2)) {
            alert("No son numeros");
            noNumber = true;
        } else if ( number1 > number2 ) {
            document.write( number1 + " Es el numero mayor");
            noNumber = false;
        } else if (number1 < number2) {
            document.write( number2 + " Es el numero mayor");
            noNumber = false;
        } else {
            document.write("Ningun numero es mayor");
            noNumber = false;
        }
    }

    while ( noNumber) {
        alert("Intentalo otra vez");
        randomNumber();        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu falla se debe a que [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) lo que devuelve es un string o null, por lo que estas usando los operadores `>` y `<` sobre strings lo cual te lleva al comportamiento inesperado ya que en javascript si comparas un string con un número se convierte a número la cadena y luego se realiza la comparación pero si se comparan dos cadenas te las va comparando letra por letra hasta que encuentra una que sea mayor que la otra. Lee http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp para que entiendas las posibles variaciones que te puedes encontrar. Intenta comparar 12 y 2 en tu algoritmo original.

Lo que debes hacer es convertir a número primero y luego comparar. Tu algoritmo se puede refactorizar de la siguiente forma.

```js
var noNumber = false;

function randomNumber() {
  var number1 = Number(prompt("Escribe un numero"));
  var number2 = Number(prompt("Escribe otro numero"));

  if (isNaN(number1) || isNaN(number2)) {
    alert("No son numeros");
    noNumber = true;
  } else if (number1 > number2) {
    document.write(number1 + " Es el numero mayor");
    noNumber = false;
  } else if (number1 < number2) {
    document.write(number2 + " Es el numero mayor");
    noNumber = false;
  } else {
    document.write("Ningun numero es mayor");
  }
}

randomNumber();
while (noNumber) {
  alert('Intentalo de nuevo');
  randomNumber();
}
```

Como verás yo uso el constructor [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) y no [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) ya que parseInt convierte 12abc en 12 y me parece que eso no es lo que quieres. Number es un poco más escricto y si la cadena **no es un estrictamente un número** devuelve NaN.

No hay necesidad de escribir `document.write(randomNumber());` ya que `randomNumber` no tiene ninguna instrucción `return` y por lo tanto devuelve `undefined` por lo que estarías escribiendo `document.write(undefined);`

Answer (score 0):

Primero se ejecuta el randomNumber(); de la 3ra línea (ya de paso te aconsejo definir las funciones ANTES de usarlas, te ahorrara problemas en un futuro)
Después, en la funcion, si las dos variables numero1 y numero2 contiene un numero (o nada), noNumber será false, por lo tanto en ese caso, al terminar ese primer randomMumber, NO entrará en el while.
después del while hay un document.write(randomNumber()); que ejecutarà otra vez randomNumber, haciendo el write de dentro la funcion, pero como no retorna nada, el "write" de esa línea será "undefined"
No se exactamente de pretendías que hiciera... si quieres que el bucle se efectúe hasta que una de las variables no sea un numero, lo podrias hacer así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<META charset=utf-8>

<SCRIPT>

var noNumber;

function randomNumber () {
    var number1 = prompt("Escribe un numero");
    var number2 = prompt("Escribe otro numero");
    noNumber = isNaN(number1) || isNaN(number2) || !number1 || !number2;
    if (noNumber) alert("Almenos uno de los dos no es un numero");
    else if ( number1 > number2 ) document.write( number1 + " Es el numero mayor<br>");
    else if (number1 < number2) document.write( number2 + " Es el numero mayor<br>");
    else document.write("Ningun numero es mayor<br>");
}

do {
    randomNumber(); 
    if (!noNumber) alert("Intentalo otra vez");           
}while (!noNumber)

</SCRIPT>
```